A teen slasher movie took place in a limited area
I couldn't remember the name of a movie that I've watched a while ago . 

It's a 2000 - 2010 made, a low budget teen slasher movie. Couldn't remember if it's a USA made or not. But definitely not Asian or south american made. Probably IMDb rating is below 5/10. 
The whole movie takes place in a limited area. Just a underground club, underground car park, etc.
The movie starts with a party. All attendants are young. It could be a celebration / end of term party I don't know. When it's over just over 10 people left in the place. A girl finds a body and screams. After that the murderer kills his victims one by one. He also cuts the electricity. I remember it's too dark. At the end just a girl and a young man survives. They reach a mall under the tunnels connected with the underground club and the underground car park. I remember the sun rising when they reach the mall an survived . 
The girl who survived wears a jean and light purple / light blue camisole. She's around 1.65. She has medium brown hair. She's around 20 - 25. The young man is short black haired and injured. 
There's no paranormal stuff in the movie like ghosts, jinn, dead souls etc.
The murderer may send images / videos to the people to locate the bodies but i'm not quite sure of this.

Also, The opening scene was at the underground small place which %70 of the movie took place in and the dancing zone was similar to a standard high school stage.
The car park that was like a mall's loading / unloading area. There wasn't any car in it.
It was a low budget movie and probably rated below 5 / 10 at IMDb.
It's similar to Pray for the Morning ( 2006 ) except the paranormal stuff. The ending scene and the survivors are also very similar to the movie that I've been looking for.

It's similar to Pray for the Morning ( 2006 ) except the paranormal stuff . The ending scene and the survivors are also very similar to the movie that i've been looking for .

@durida It's better if you merge all of your accounts, refer here for details and submit you improvement in question itself rather then answer.

For once, I'd like to see a slasher movie that didn't take place in a limited area. Like, if James Bond were a spree killer.

The Choke (2006)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0424890/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt

The movie is called Death Tunnel (2005)
Years ago I watched this same movie on television and always remembered it. After years of wondering what that movie was I went on an extensive online search for it until finally I found it. 
Everything in your description matches what I had remembered. Started with a party in a creepy place. Every hour a girl got killed. The ending was just two people surviving, one of them a girl. One of them a boy. They got out of the building, but they to had to go back into the building to "find a cure" cliffhanger. Low budget, made for tv looking. Slasher film.


Don't use answer to post you comments and kindly merge both of you accounts, refer here for details

The Choke (2006)

A hot young band playing at clubs and raves across the Northwest. Handsome lead singer Dylan Brown has a bit of an ego problem, guitarist Mike Prichard is a true womanizer, dark and mysterious bassist Beatrice London has a death and destruction fetish, and drummer Robert "Nancy Boy" Nancy just wants everybody to get along. Nevertheless, one thing is for sure, they rock! Unknown to the rest of the band, Dylan and Mike have decided to go solo; unfortunately they choose to play their last gig at a rave at the notorious Club 905 a performance that will change their lives forever. When club owner Guy Johnson runs out of alcohol he quickly loses the crowds. Mysteriously the band finds itself trapped in the cavernous, old meat packing plant that is now Club 905, along with Guy's red-hot, intriguing girlfriend Star and Dylan's sweetie Vanessa Jones lovingly called Jonesy. Tension increases when the mutilated body of a flirty groupie turns up in a meat locker and the group realizes they are locked in with a vicious killer. Gruesome slaughter, fear and death stalk the band and their friends through the labyrinth of rooms and passageways of the old building. As secrets are revealed, people turn up dead, bodies disappear, and emotions run rampant as everybody turns into a suspect. As the body count rises, they must stick together to survive and find a way out.

