A Subterranean horror movie
I'm looking for a subterranean teen slasher movie from the 2000's. I watched it 3-4 years ago, so it shouldn't be newer than 2012. Unfortunately I watched it dubbed in my language, so I couldn't remember if it was USA made or not. But I can say it wasn't Asian, South American or Australian made. My best guess is it was a USA, Canada or Middle Europe made movie. The duration of the movie was about between 90 and 120 mins. It was a low budget movie, and the cast was about 10 teens aged 20-25, and a killer. 
99% of the movie took place underground, except the last 1-2 minutes at the end. Another point is the time period in the movie is 5-6 hours, between midnight and the sunrise. At the beginning of the movie, there was a scene of the ending of a celebration at some underground place. It wasn't a club, bar, a place with security, bartender, DJ, etc. It was a small place, probably a basement of a building for just a group of friends having fun. Think about a standard high school stage. The area was about that big. There was a long rectangular desk with drinks, ice, etc. 
When the celebration was over, there were just about ten teens left. They were cleaning up the mess, and getting rid of decorations. Suddenly they figured out that one of their friends was missing. They thought that he was joking and tried to find him. One of the girls found the body and screamed. The others ran toward the screams, and were shocked when they found the body. They tried to call the police but there was no signal. 
After that scene they were panicked, separated and tried to escape from there. The exits were blocked, and the killer had cut the power. It was too dark and the only lights were Zippos, flashlights, phone lights, etc. The group was separated, and they tried to find a way out. There were lots of doors and halls in the basement.  He/She teased them by sending images of the bodies to the group. When they found the body, the killer had already escaped. It continued like that while he/she killed the teens one by one until finally only 2 teens were left. He/She didn't use any firearms to kill, the bodies had stab wounds.
One of them was a girl. She was white, medium sized, aged 20-25, and had brown medium hair, with brown eyes.  She wore blue jeans, with a blue or light purple top. The other one was a boy and he was injured. He was white, kind of short for a man, aged 20-25, and had a little bronze skin, black hair, and dark eyes. 
The basement was connected to other buildings’ basements with tunnels and corridors. 
They moved forward underground, and finally they reached an unlocked exit. They reached an empty building, and there was an escalator that didn't work. They went up and finally reached the outside at the end of the movie. The identification of the killer went unrevealed.  
I checked some similar movies. It isn't Pray for Morning, The Mine, Underground, Outsiders, Urban Explorer, The Tunnel and Death Tunnel. There wasn't any fiction objects or any myth stories or legends or monsters etc. It was a typical teen slasher movie which took place underground. 

http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57338/a-teen-slasher-movie-took-place-in-a-limited-area

@pori Unfortunately this isn't the movie that i'm looking for.

These two questions are not the same?

@pori I checked it, it's similar but the answer was wrong. The one who asked question didn't approve the answer by the way.

Could it be DeadTime (2012)?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOCqum_UPW0

@pori No,this isn't. The story is completely different and there are much more people at the cast. Thanks anyway.

Choke (2006)

A hot young band playing at clubs and raves across the Northwest. Handsome lead singer Dylan Brown has a bit of an ego problem, guitarist Mike Prichard is a true womanizer, dark and mysterious bassist Beatrice London has a death and destruction fetish, and drummer Robert "Nancy Boy" Nancy just wants everybody to get along. Nevertheless, one thing is for sure, they rock! Unknown to the rest of the band, Dylan and Mike have decided to go solo; unfortunately they choose to play their last gig at a rave at the notorious Club 905 a performance that will change their lives forever. 
  When club owner Guy Johnson runs out of alcohol he quickly loses the crowds. Mysteriously the band finds itself trapped in the cavernous, old meat packing plant that is now Club 905, along with Guy's red-hot, intriguing girlfriend Star and Dylan's sweetie Vanessa Jones lovingly called Jonesy. Tension increases when the mutilated body of a flirty groupie turns up in a meat locker and the group realizes they are locked in with a vicious killer. Gruesome slaughter, fear and death stalk the band and their friends through the labyrinth of rooms and passageways of the old building. 
  As secrets are revealed, people turn up dead, bodies disappear, and emotions run rampant as everybody turns into a suspect. As the body count rises, they must stick together to survive and find a way out. 


Could it possibly be the answer to this one too?

Yes, definitely :)

Well, you can always answer that one too, then. ;) [If it's a duplicate, that would be determined later.]
